# How to remove an extra scope from Google (editor) add-on live project (Prepared in Apps Scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-developers-console, google-workspace-add-ons

My Google (sheets) editor add-on code has been changed and now my project doesn't use Google drive access now. And I want to remove that scope from my project. The Add-on is live and being used by the users. *I don't want to show them "unverified" app dialogue.* I have the highest drive scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" approved earlier and now Google asks to reverify all restricted scopes. However I want to remove it completely, and don't want any of the drive scopes. Since all the following questions are inter related, I am asking them together.

**My first question is**, at which places I have to change and in which order ? [I have to remove that scope from 1. my Apps Script project's manifest file and 2. from OAuth consent screen of console.google.com and (probably ?) 3.I have to submit for verification. Which order I have to follow.]

**Second question:** How can I prepare a video showing OAuth consent screen, while I haven't updated my code.

**Third question:** Should I remove the below code from manifest file ? (Is there any trick to know whether this service is used anywhere in my code ?)
It is under "dependencies" >
"enabledAdvancedServices":

```
    {
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    },
```

**Fourth question:** Should I remove this API from console project too ?

**References:**

1. [get-smart-about-preparing-your-app-for-OAuth-verfication](https://developers.googleblog.com/2019/09/get-smart-about-preparing-your-app-for-OAuth-verfication.html). *Here I can't find any help for reverification. However they have mentioned in a paragraph:
   "Similarly, if you need to add new scopes to your application, you’ll need to get those scopes approved before you launch the functionality into your production app (a test client is going to be essential here).*"
   **Can you help me understand this comment in the bracket, how to create and user the test client ?**

- [Five annoying issues with Google’s OAuth Scope Verification.](https://www.gmass.co/blog/five-annoying-issues-google-oauth-scope-verification/) It is useful. There is a section: "The steps to add a scope later are:" under the section 2. Here he has mentioned that first we should update the scopes on console.cloud.google.com under consent screen settings and then to submit for verification. However I have a doubt, whether I understand it correctly or not. And in this case, how can I prepare a video of consent screen?

3. [Google Oauth removing scopes from access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536874/google-oauth-removing-scopes-from-access). It is also not answering my questions.